# The proper way to install and configure @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor with TypeScript and Cypress 10+

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to implement cypress-cucumber-preprocessor for Cypress 11 with TypeScript, but I am unsure what I miss.
Here are the steps that I do:

1. Install it with the following command:

> npm install @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

2. Here is my problem. I am unsure how to implement the plugin inside the "cypress.config.ts" file. The issue is that I am still using the workaround for old implemented plugins with 'return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)'. Is there a way to use both implementations (one for calling the 'index.js' file and the second for adding the cypress-cucumber-preprocessor plugin)? I am not sure how to process it.

```
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";

export default defineConfig({
  projectId: '7emkc5',
  reporter: 'mochawesome',
  reporterOptions: {
    reportDir: 'cypress/report/mochawesome-report',
    overwrite: false,
    html: true,
    json: true,
    timestamp: 'dd-mm-yyyy_HH-MM-ss',
  },
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  e2e: {
    // We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
    // You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  },
})

I am using the last version of Cypress 11.1.0 and typescript.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just follow the guide to install TS https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Install-TypeScript

then, paste this https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md in your cypress.config.ts

install bahmutov lib too:

```
npm i @bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor
```

this works for me... good luck!

Comment: Yes, this helps me a lot. I will write the exact steps in the answer block. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Set `compilerOptions.moduleResolution` to `node16` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Users that are unable to upgrade moduleResolution to node16, can use the paths property as a workaround, like shown below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/*": ["./node_modules/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/dist/subpath-entrypoints/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the clean flow to add the plugin to Cypress 10+ with TypeScript:

1. Install NodeJS (supported version from Cypress).
2. Install Cypress.
3. Install/add [TypeScript support for Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Install-TypeScript).
4. Add [@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor) plugin to the project.
5. Add [@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor) plugin to the project.
6. Add the e[xample setup](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md#example-setup) to the cypress.config.ts class.

However, now I have a different problem. It seems that I am not able to add some plugins to the 'setupNodeEvents' method. I ask a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74501311/cypress-10-add-second-plugin-block-to-work-with-badeball-cypress-cucumber-prep).