# Cypress 10+ add second plugin block to work with @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Tags: typescript, plugins, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I try adding the @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor plugin to my Cypress 10+ version. But I met some strange error when I tried to use another plugin (like cy-verify-downloads). Before that, everything was working as expected. When I try to execute some random (any) test, I receive the following errors:

> node_modules/cy-verify-downloads/src/index.js:1:25: ERROR: Could not resolve "path"
> node_modules/cy-verify-downloads/src/index.js:2:44: ERROR: Could not resolve "fs"
> node_modules/cy-verify-downloads/src/index.js:3:32: ERROR: Could not resolve "crypto"

I isolate the problem, but I am not sure why it is happening.

Here is the code of cypress.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
const { verifyDownloadTasks } = require('cy-verify-downloads');
import createBundler from "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import createEsbuildPlugin from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild";

export default defineConfig({
  projectId: '7emkc5',
  reporter: 'mochawesome',
  reporterOptions: {
    reportDir: 'cypress/report/mochawesome-report',
    overwrite: false,
    html: true,
    json: true,
    timestamp: 'dd-mm-yyyy_HH-MM-ss',
  },
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  e2e: {
    async setupNodeEvents(on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
      config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {

      // Integrate the cy-verify-downloads plugin.
      on('task', verifyDownloadTasks);

      // Integrate @bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor plugin.
      const createBundler = require('@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor')
      module.exports = (on, config) => {
        on('file:preprocessor', createBundler())
      };

      // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
      on(
        "file:preprocessor",
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        })
      );
      // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
      return config;

    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,feature}',
  },
})
```

The issue appeared when I added..

```
: Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions>
```

..and...

```
     // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
      on(
        "file:preprocessor",
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        })
      );
      // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
      return config;
```

...to the "setupNodeEvents" method.

Comment: There is a solution that skips the error but blocks the plugins that need these configurations.
The solution for skipping the functionality is to add "false" values for all of the variables in the browser block in the package.json class.

Add the following code inside the {root}/package.json class:
```
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "path": false,
    "fs": false
  }
```

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the preprocessor I added (@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor).

Comment: It is not possible. It should be used two preprocessors, and it is impossible (or I need help finding the solution).
Source: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5832#issuecomment-1109849015.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: Anyone got any solution for this.

Comment: I had the same issue and I solved removing any cypress.config.ts import, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/77820645/5081063